# Multiplicative inverse of a rational number

Tags: c++, unix

Below is a stub program, the inverse function returns the multiplicative inverse of a rational number.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

unsigned inverse(unsigned&, unsigned&);

int main()
{
    unsigned p, q;

    cout << "Enter a rational number ==> ";
    cin >> p >> q;
    inverse(p, q);
    cout << p << ":" << q << endl;

    return 0;
}

unsigned inverse(unsigned& p, unsigned& q) 
// returns the multiplicative inverse
{
   unsigned swap;
   swap = p;
   p = q;
   q = swap;

   return p;
}
```

I'm trying to incorporate the inverse function in a bigger program and I am finding it difficult to do so. The functions header must be `Rational inverse() const;` This is a member function in class Rational. _p and _q are declared in the class. The function is a const so I cant change the values of _p and _q. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Assuming you have a constructor `Rational(unsigned p, unsigned q)`, then the `inverse()` *member* function would be something like: `Rational inverse() const { return Rational(_q, _p); }`.

Comment: Oh yes I do, thank you so much for pointing that out to me.

Answer (score 0):

You will want the body of `Rational inverse() const` to include a few things if i'm understanding your question correctly. First create a new Rational that you have the privilege of modifying. Then set this Rational to be an inverse and return it from the function.

```
Rational inverse() const {
   Rational temp; // creates Rational you can modify
    //..appropriate operations on temp to ....
    //..set temp._p and temp._q to be the inverse...
   return temp; 
}
```

Make sure to collect the rational from the function call like so:

```
int main(){
   Rational a;
   Rational inverseOfa = a.inverse();
   return 0;
}
```